# Pandas select_dtypes does not work for transposed dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove **rows** that contain non-numeric values in a DataFrame.
My approach was to use the .select_dtypes() on a transposed df, but then it return empty. Why?

```
#DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[20,111],'B':[222,200],'C':[3,'a']}, index = ['I','II'])

#If I perform the method on the original df it works well
print(data.select_dtypes('number'))

#But if I transpose the df first, the return is empty
print(data.T.select_dtypes('number'))
```

Answer (score 2):

[pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) uses homogenenous dtypes **per column** if possible.

When transposing, this converts the dtypes to the common dtype (floats + int -> float, strings + number -> object).

In your case, the strings are forcing the object dtype once transposed:

```
data.T.dtypes

I     object
II    object
dtype: object
```